# Is there a vector field such that one differential form is the Lie derivative of the other?

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential-operators

I'm looking for a reference or answer for the following question:

Let $M$ be an (compact and orientable, if it helps) smooth manifold and $\nu$ and $\mu$ two differential forms. I'm looking for conditions that allow me to find a vector field $X$ on $M$ such that $\nu=\mathcal{L}_X\mu$, where $\mathcal{L}$ denotes the Lie derivative on differential forms.

A special case in which I'm particularly interested in is if $\mu$ is a positive volume form with $\int_M\mu=1$ and $\nu$ is a volume form with $\int_M\nu=0$. Then the above question can be rephrased as: given a smooth function $\varphi$ with $\int_M\varphi\mu=0$, can we find a vector field $X$ such that $\varphi=\text{div}_{\mu}X$?

I've read somewhere that under certain assumptions one can always find such a vector field, but I cannot find that statement anymore and so I would appreciate if someone knew a short answer or a reference for this.

Comment: In the general case, for given $\mu$ and $\nu$, the equation $\mathcal{L}_X\mu=\nu$ is highly overdetermined, and there will be no solution.  For example, if $\mu$ is closed and $\nu$ is not, then there is no solution, since $\mathcal{L}_X$ commutes with the exterior derivative $\mathrm{d}$.

Comment: @Robert: Yes, I'm not very optimistic. Another way of looking at this question is that it is an infinitesimal version of the question, given two $k$-forms, can we find a diffeomorphism that pulls back one to the other one? So we could ask: is there a class of manifolds for which there is a nice characterization of the orbits of Diff$(M)$ acting on $\Omega^k(M)$? The infinitesimal question would be phrased in terms of the Lie algebra of Diff$(M)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\mu$ is a volume form and  $\nu$ is a top degree form, then there exists a vector field $X$ such that $L_X\mu=\nu$ if and only if $\nu$ is exact.

You can always  fix a metric $g$ on $M$ such that $\mu$ is the volume form 
 determined by the metric and the orientation, $\mu=dVol_g$.

Denote by $\DeclareMathOperator{\Vect}{Vect}$ $\Vect(M)$ the space of  smooth vector fields on $M$ and by  $\ast$ the Hodge  star operator determined by $g$ and the orientation.  Then $\mu=\ast 1$.

For any vector field $X$  on $M$ denote by $\omega_X\in \Omega^1(M)$   the $1$-form dual to $X$, i.e.,
$$
\omega_X(Y)=g(X,Y),\;\;\forall Y\in \Vect(M). 
$$
Then (see Proposition 4.1.48 of [these notes](https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf)) $\DeclareMathOperator{\dive}{div}$
$$
\dive_\mu X=\dive_g X=\ast d\ast  \omega_X\Longleftrightarrow \nu=\ast \dive X=d\ast\omega_X.
$$
Thus if there exists a vector field $X$ such that $L_X\mu=\nu$ then $\nu$ is exact $\nu=d\ast\omega_X$, i.e., $\nu$ is exact. Conversely, if $\nu$ is exact, $\nu=d\beta$, then  the vector field $X$ uniquely  characterized by the equality $\ast\omega_X=\beta$ satisfies $L_X\mu=\nu$.

**Remark.** If $M$ is compact and connected  then $\nu$ is exact if ad only if $\int_M\nu=0$. If $M$ is noncompact and connected then $\nu$ is automatically exact since $H_{DR}^{\dim M}(M)=0$. If $M$ has several connected components solve this problem on each component separately.

Comment: After pondering your answer for a bit, isn't exactness of $\nu$ already sufficient for the case $k=n$ (regardless of compactness of $M$)? I may be missing something. But if $\nu=d\eta$, can't we can just chose a Riemannian metric as you do and then choose $X$ as one of $\pm\sharp\ast\eta$?

Comment: On a compact, connecetd oriented manifold  a top degree  form is exact if and only if its integral is zero.

Comment: I do not understand  the meaning of $\sharp$

Comment: Thanks, I think this clears up most things. I try to summarize: on any orientable manifold, exactness of $\nu$ is equivalent to being a Lie derivative of a volume form. On a manifold without boundary, an exact top degree form integrates to zero. In general, a form that integrates to zero does not need to be exact. So in general the question is equivalent to asking whether the top degree de Rham cohomology vanishes. On a compact manifold you showed that the vanishing of the integral is sufficient for exactness. Where does connectedness enter in your answer?

Comment: BTW, $\sharp$ is the isomorphism that maps one-forms to vector fields.

Comment: On noncompact (orientable) manifolds the top cohomology  is trivial. Also, due to noncompactness not every top degree form  is integrable over the manifold. On  compact disconnected manifold,  say with two components, you can have a form that integrates to 1 on one component and to -1 on the other component so the total integral is zero without being exact. The dimension of the top DeRham  cohomology  is equal to the number of components.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The remaining question is whether in the non-compact case $\int_M\alpha=0$ is sufficient?

Comment: In the noncompact (orientable)case every top degree form $\alpha$ is *exact* ,$\alpha =d\beta$ so  $\\ast \alpha =\pm \ast d(\ast \ast\beta)=\pm d^*(\ast\beta)$. The result is true inthis case as well.

Comment: So it seems that in the compact orientable case connectedness is both necessary and sufficient for every top degree form that integrates to zero to be representable by a Lie derivative of a volume form, while in the non-compact orientable case it is always possible regardless of connectedness. Would you like to add this to your answer?

Comment: A noncompact manifold can have a compact component a noncompact one. The  necessary and sufficient condition is that  the top degree form $\alpha$ be exact.

Comment: I've updated my answer.